# How to handle with iframe under <script> tag in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I have some problem with iframe, which is under script tag. I don't have any idea how to switch to this iframe using Selenium. Do you have any idea how to handle wit that? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: can you show view source of the element ?

Comment: You can use drive.switchTo("frame name");

Comment: @AmitJain I tried but in the iFrame tag is only link to the page. Something like <iframe src = ""></iframe>

Comment: [check this out](https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html)